# Turn on/off charging sound & vibration in android 11

Tags: android, android-11

Currently stuck on an issue as I need to turn on/off the charging sound & vibration programmatically in android 11. As I check for many blogs and stack answers but didn't get the clarification that how to do this in Android 11. Any help will be appreciable.